# Webcam WebRTC in python

Tags: python, websocket, webrtc

I've been looking around but without much luck. I know that WebRTC is still largely an experiment but there are few to none working examples and they all seem to be related to nodejs, whereas the application I'm writing is in python. Is it possible to achieve a webcamera chat in a python environment(flask, tornado, django, cherrypy, all fine with me)?

Answer (score -2):

There's some misunderstanding here.

WebRTC isn't an experiment - it is a real specification that is available today by two browsers already (Chrome and Firefox). It has been adopted by virtually all the industry (only company I can think of who is still mum about it is Apple).

Being a browser technology, there's nothing barring you from using whatever technology in the backend that you wish. Python is a good choice as any.

Check [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/saghul/webrtc-44106786) for some information on how to fit WebRTC into a Python project.

My own choice would be to go with [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

You should